# How can I get my data to group by experiment within each week (boxplot)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting data from three experiments in which data was collected each week for three weeks plus the starting point (0, 1, 2, and 3).  I want each experiment to be represented by a shape, and each week's boxplot show the data from each experiment for that week. As you can see, the experiments are just plotting left to right, rather than grouping by week. I tried adding a group=BP$Week function in geom_point, but it didn't fix the problem.  Any advice?

Here is my code:

```
k <- BO %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Week, `Vertical Travel Distance (mm)`)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = Week)) + 
  geom_point(shape=BO$Experiment, size=2, alpha=0.8, 
             position=position_dodge2(width = 0.75)) + 
  ylim(-80,0)
```

And sample data:

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHDyY.png)

[Data not plotting by experiment correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhxLb.png)

Comment: Please share sample data as copy/pasteable text, not a picture. `dput(BO[1:10, ])` will give us the first 10 rows, choose a suitable subset to illustrate the problem.

Comment: If you want a different boxplot for each Week and for each experiment, then the `group` needs to use both of those, e.g., `group = interaction(Week, Experiment)`. I'd also recommend putting the shape inside `aes`, aes(shape = Experiment)`. If you need more help than that, please do share data in a way we can use it.